# Is Underscore.js functional programming a fake?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

According to my understanding of functional programming, you should be able to **chain** multiple functions and then execute the whole chain by **going through the input data once**.

In other words, when I do the following (pseudo-code):

```
list = [1, 2, 3];
sum_squares = list
   .map(function(item) { return item * item; })
   .reduce(function(total, item) { return total + item; }, 0);
```

I expect that the list will be traversed **once**, when each value will be squared and then everything will be added up (hence, the map operation would be called as needed by the reduce operation).

However, when I look at the source code of Underscore.js, I see that all the "functional programming" functions actually produce intermediate collections like, for example, so:

```
// Return the results of applying the iteratee to each element.
_.map = _.collect = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
  iteratee = cb(iteratee, context);
  var keys = !isArrayLike(obj) && _.keys(obj),
      length = (keys || obj).length,
      results = Array(length);
  for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
    var currentKey = keys ? keys[index] : index;
    results[index] = iteratee(obj[currentKey], currentKey, obj);
  }
  return results;
};
```

So the question is, as stated in the title, are we fooling ourselves that we do functional programming when we use Underscore.js?

What we actually do is *make program look like functional programming* without actually it being functional programming in fact. Imagine, I build a long chain of K filter() functions on list of length N, and then in Underscore.js my computational complexity will be O(K*N) instead of O(N) as would be expected in functional programming.

P.S. I've heard a lot about functional programming in JavaScript, and I was expecting to see some functions, generators, binding... Am I missing something?

Comment: `According to my understanding of functional programming, you should be  able to chain multiple functions` - what about mutation? Is it preferred?

Comment: JavaScript is not lazy. A non-lazy way to do things would involve something like the *transducer* concept recently added to Clojure.

Comment: Please notice that `O(K*N)` for a constant `K` is the very same as `O(N)`

Comment: @Bergi - yes, you are right. It will still be K times slower though :)

Comment: @Bergi - and require intermediate memory.

Comment: @akuz Iterating over a sequence twice, doing one thing on each iteration, is not twice as slow as iterating over it once, doing two things on each iteration. In terms of number of operations the difference will be much less than that. In terms of actual running time, it may be less or even more depending on various factors.

Comment: @sepp2k you're right. Okay, the only problem left then is the creation of the full intermediate collection taking up memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is Underscore.js functional programming a fake?

No, Underscore does have lots of useful functional helper functions. But yes, [they're doing it wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3svKOdZijA). You may want to have a look at [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) instead.

> I expect that the list will be traversed once

Yes, `list` will only be traversed once. It won't be mutated, it won't be held in memory (if you had not a variable reference to it). What `reduce` traverses is a different list, the one produced by `map`.

> All the functions actually produce intermediate collections

Yes, that's the simplest way to implement this in a language like JavaScript. Many people rely on `map` executing all its callbacks before `reduce` is called, as they use side effects. JS does not enforce pure functions, and library authors don't want to confuse people.

Notice that even in pure languages like Haskell an intermediate structure is built<sup>1</sup>, though it would be consumed lazily so that it never is allocated as a whole.

There are libraries that implement this kind of optimisation in strict languages with the concept of [transducers](http://clojure.org/transducers) as known from Clojure. Examples in JS are [transduce](https://github.com/transduce/transduce), [transducers-js](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/transducers-js), [transducers.js](https://github.com/jlongster/transducers.js) or [underarm](https://github.com/kevinbeaty/underarm). Underscore and Ramda have been looking into them<sup>2</sup> too.

> I was expecting to see some […] generators

Yes, generators/iterators that can be consumed lazily are another choice. You'll want to have a look at [Lazy.js](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/), [highland](http://highlandjs.org/), or [immutable-js](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js).

<sub>[1]: Well, [not really](https://wiki.haskell.org/Short_cut_fusion) - it's a too easy optimisation

[2]: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/1896, https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/865</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Functional programming has nothing to do with traversing a sequence once; even Haskell, which is as pure as you're going to get, will traverse the length of a strict list twice if you ask it to `filter pred (map f x)`.

Functional programming is *a simpler model of computation* where the only things that are allowed to happen do not include side effects. For example, in Haskell basically only the following things are allowed to happen:

1. You can apply a value `f` to another value `x`, producing a new value `f x` with no side-effects. The first value `f` is called a "function". It must be the case that any time you apply the same `f` to the same `x` you get the same answer for `f x`.
2. You can give a name to a value, which might be a function or a simple value or whatever.
3. You can define a new structure for data with a new type signature, and/or structure some data with those "constructors."
4. You can define a new type-class or show how an existing data structure instantiates a type-class.
5. You can "pattern match" a data structure, which is a combination of a case dispatch with naming the parts of the data structure for the rest of your project.

Notice how "print something to the console" is not doable in Haskell, nor is "alter an existing data structure." To print something to the console, you construct a value which represents the action of printing something to the console, and then give it a special name, `main`. (When you're compiling Haskell, you compute the action named `main` and then write it to disk as an executable program; when you run the program, that action is actually completed.) If there is already a `main` program, you figure out where you want to include the new action in the existing actions of that program, then use a function to sequence the console logging with the existing actions. The Haskell program never *does* anything; it just *represents* doing something.

That is the essence of functional programming. It is weaker than normal programming languages where the language itself does stuff, like JavaScript's `console.log()` function which immediately performs its side effect whenever the JS interpreter runs through it. In particular, there are some things which are (or seem to be) O(1) or O(log(log(n))) in normal programs where our best functional equivalent is O(log(n)).

Comment: Haskell will not traverse the list twice. When the first element is needed, both `filter` and `map` are executed just enough to get at the first element. Then when the second element is needed, they are executed further until the second element. And so on. So that's exactly what the OP expects, but it's a property of Haskell being lazy, not of it being functional.

Comment: instead of "traversing a sequence twice" you should say "traverses two sequences".

Comment: Sorry, I said 'sequence' because I meant 'sequence', as in `Data.Sequence`. I will update the statement to be more explicit about this.

Comment: You seem to be confusing functional (or even declarative) programming with lazy evaluation just as the OP did. And in your first sentence you state that they have nothing to do with this?

Comment: Please notice that functional programming is not in any way "weaker" than "normal" programming languages. Are you implying they would use a different [model of computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation)?

Comment: "You seem to be confusing functional (or even declarative) programming with lazy evaluation...?"  -- You seem to not have read my whole answer?

"Please notice that functional programming is not in any way 'weaker'" -- it is in precisely the way that I explained: there are many problems, let's call them "imperatively oriented" problems or so, where we do not know how to get asymptotically the same running time for functional languages that we can for imperative ones.

Comment: @ChrisDrost: I did read the whole answer, that's why I've commented. You seem to describe "functional programming" as a) lazy b) pure c) immutable-only. None of those is true. And no, functional languages can solve all problems in the same complexity bounds as other languages. Even if the solution look more imperative, this doesn't mean it is not functional.

Comment: Well then we've got a disagreement about what I was saying. I was trying to say that laziness is inessential, and you are saying that I said laziness was essential. Do you have specific advice for how I might correct your perception of what I'm saying above? (If we're talking about functional programming then we *are* talking about purity. E.g. Common Lisp is a hybrid language made by taking a functional language and adding mutation and macros to it. It's surely not functional *by virtue of having setters*, rather that's one of the ways that it *fails* to be functional.)

Comment: Thanks for you pointing out my confusion between lazy evaluation and functional programming. One thing I was wondering about then, is whether Underscore.js is just a syntactic sugar then? I was expecting to get the benefits of lazy evaluation. But in fact, Underscore.js code would be equivalent to: var list = [1, 2, 3]; var squares = []; for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { squares.push (list[i]*list[i]); }; var sum_squares = 0; for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) { sum_squares += squares[i]; };

Comment: Okay, Underscore.js will hide the intermediate array from me... But that's not the point. In my view, almost all the benefits of functional programming in such way are eliminated without lazy evaluation... Can what Underscore.js does be then actually called functional programming??? It's just a set of utility functions in my view...

Comment: @akuz: Yes, underscore is a functional programming library. But as functional programming is all about functions, yes, everything is just a set of utility functions…

Comment: @Bergi - thanks! it's not what I was expecting at all... disappointed... I was expecting some real stuff like in Scala...

Comment: @akuz: If you are looking for a js functional programming library "done right", have a look at http://ramdajs.com/

Comment: @Bergi - thanks so much! Judging from their front page, it *is* exactly what I was expecting / looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: @Bergi: if you make your comment about ramdajs.com into an answer, I will upvote it.